# How do I get jQuery lists to persist data to the database in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to create a series of questions with jQuery, maybe jQuery mobile.  For each question I want it to have two answers. I want the list of questions to appear on the same page.

Maybe something like this...

(Question here)

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <legend>Yes or No</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-orientation" id="isVertical" value="isVertical" checked="checked">
        <label for="isVertical">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-orientation" id="isHorizontal" value="isHorizontal">
        <label for="isHorizontal">No</label>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I can't seem to find any information on linking the button to the user. 
So when the user picks one of the buttons, I want to store their choice into the "choice" attribute of their quiz.

I don't want anyone to write code for me I just need a general idea on how to get a jQuery button click to put the user's choice in the database. For each question.

Comment: Check out this railscasts episode on [multistep form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks but I want it all on the same page. I don't know if I will make it like a form above or perhaps a <ul> with <li> to click on and send data with the choice attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle the above problem using many different ways but, I will list an approach down below.

You can create 2 models.

1. model to store the tempdata
2. model to store the actual data after the form is submitted.

When the form is submitted you should delete the record from the tempdata model.

As the user is filling out the form you can utilize the [jquery autosave](https://github.com/nervetattoo/jquery-autosave) plugin to send data to the tempdata model.

Using the above approach if the user is filling out a long form or a series of questions they will have the ability to resume where they left off if something were to happen(lost internet connection, etc).

As for linking a user to a specific question... You will need to think about how you are going to design your models. For example I would have a `user model`, `question model` and a `answers model`. In your case the question model would have a user_id attribute (foreign key) which allows you to link a specific question to a specific user. Check out this [nested forms tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) from railscast for a better explanation.

Hope this helps!